# http post + digital certificate required

Tags: httpwebrequest, http-post, digital-certificate

I want to post some xml to an external server and have been told that:

"The transmission protocol used is https (SSL). This requires that your initiating server has a valid digital certificate."

Where do I get one of these? I have a Thwate Personal Email Certificate but not sure if that would do?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using HttpWebRequest, you shouldn't have a problem assuming that the server you are posting to is using a valid SSL certificate.  Just give HttpWebRequest the https url and let it go.

Comment: ok I'm using PHP to post this xml.
so I shouldn't need a certificate even though it says: "This requires that your initiating server has a valid digital certificate."

Comment: From that, it sounds like they want you to have a certificate too. Not sure why, it seems a little silly...

Comment: sorry, you tagged it httpwebrequest which is a .net thing.  PHP works the same way though.  As long as the the certificate authority on your machine can validate the sites certificate, everything should be fine.  Years ago I wrote an authorize.net component in php that connected via https.  Unless they are adding the requirement that you sign your request with an additional certificate...